# php - running shell command using shell_exec

Tags: php

I'm using an ajax call to execute "shell_exec" on the server (centos). The line that I'm executing is the following

```
echo shell_exec("php -q /websockets/timedactions.php");
```

This is the server response:

```
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.16
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://myIpAddress
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Content-type: text/html
```

After running this command it seems that the process that it supposed to activate is not running.

Calling the same command on shell with root access

```
php -q /websockets/timedactions.php
```

works perfectly.

How can I make the script work using shell_exec ?

more info:

```
ps aux | grep httpd | awk '{print $1}' = nobody


sestatus|grep enforcing = {no result}


file permissions -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 


ls -lZ timedactions.php -rwxr-xr-x root root ? timedactions.php*
```

Comment: This will depend on your setup. What user is running the php file? Presumably, it is `www-data` or whatever your webserver's user name is. Does that user have access to the file? Does the script depend on any specific variables? Do you have any errors in your log file?

Comment: how do i know if im using SELinux ? i have no errors and there are no dependent variables but some included files. I have added #!/usr/bin/env php
to the top of the PHP files and a mentioned running the command via the console works

Comment: Im pretty sure that apache runs as "nobody"

Comment: What are the permissions you're showing? Of which file or directory? The problem is probably that this is being run by the user `nobody` and they don't have permissions to execute the script. What happens if you try `sudo -u nobody php -q /websockets/timedactions.php`?

Comment: terdon - im getting "sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo"

Comment: shell_exec("/websockets/timedactions.php"); - returns the same as mentioned in my question (just the headers)

Comment: mmm... well im running cpanel if thats relevant. im running CentOS release 6.5 (Final) on

Comment: Did you try php -f /full/path/timedactions.php? Also check if your $PATH environment contains path to php executable. try shell_exec(echo "$PATH")

Comment: echo $path returns /bin:/usr/bin. php -f... same results as before , the php script is not runnnig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well ok then

Seems the answer was pretty easy (frustrating as it can be :-) )
I just added the complete path to PHP.
Dont really know why i didnt get any errors before and why it is working (if anyone can explain)

```
shell_exec('/usr/local/bin/php -q /websockets/timedactions.php /dev/null 2>&1 &');
```

Thank you for trying...

Comment: You could change $PATH variable in /etc/init.d/apache2. Take a look at [Setting $PATH for weberver user](http://serverfault.com/questions/418952/setting-path-for-weberver-user) it is relative to ubuntu, but I think that works for CentOS too.